# Сервер, пропали пароли или юзеры! Как зайти??

Tags: active-directory, windows-server

Ни чего не понимаю в этих заморочках.
Есть сервер вирт (win 2003 serv), захожу на него через RDP.
 1. Установил на Вирт сервере AD.
 2. Потом в каком-то хелпаре сказали после установки выполнить DCPROM, для настройки AD.
 3. Этот DCPROM, что-то долго выполнял, потом попросил сменить пароль и вывел надпись "Active Derictory успешно удалена"! (Кто просил? Хоть бы раз предупредил!)

---

Но дело в том, что теперь я не могу зайти на этот вирт, ни к одному юзеру пассы не подходят.
И как это понимать?
Типа AD принял в себя управление юзерами, а когда приказал долго жить и юзеров с собою унёс?
А как тогда удалять AD?
Куда юзеры-то деются?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После удаления АД с помощью dcpromo вас попросили ввести пароль местного администратора. Вот под ним и заходите. Остальные же пользователи были удалены вместе с АД, если, конечно, с домене не было второго доменного контроллера.Имя администратора для русской винды: "Администратор", для английской: "Administrator" Попробуйте и так и так. И проверьте какой домен вы указываете при входе.Мой опыт говорит, что если в системе начались подобные косяки, то проще восстановиться из резервной копии, чем разгребать глюки, которые могут выплывать в неожиданных местах.

Comment: Спасибо, про местного Админа, как-то из головы вылетело.